# Unity Starter Asset Fog

Tags: unity-game-engine

I haven't been in Unity for a while and the **starter** asset has this *fog of war* thing going on on the playground scene.

Any idea how to turn that off?

[image]

Comment: Hard to tell .. maybe [Deferred Fog](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.postprocessing@2.1/manual/Deferred-Fog.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check the skybox in the project settings, i believe there is an option for fog.

Comment: Got me to the right place! thank you!